# Active bounty "flip-card" graphic nitpick

Tags: discussion, status-completed, bounty, advertising

Don't mean to be overly critical / nitpicky....  but every time I see this graphic..

[image]

my *not-horribly-or-excessively OCD*, yet *atmittedly design-concious* brain has to stop, look, and do a double-take at this rendering.  Its missing the gap between the "cards", *or something*..  It would look "more real", maybe, like this quick pixel-hack..

[image]

Again, not the end of the world.. Just a suggestion.

Comment: I like the gap ... Let's see what the designers say.

Comment: Also. Ewwwww why should we implement needless skeuomorphism? Who do we think we are? Steve Jobs cousins? [/obligatory] [/sarcasm]

Comment: wow. there's a new one (skeuomorphism).  [word of the day!](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/design-theory/skeuomorphism-in-interface-design/).  and please, don't make the site like iCal. **please**.

Comment: you must be new here :)

Comment: See also [Skeu It!](http://skeu.it/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Skeu.it!]

[status-completed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Comment: Also changed up the font a little. I got tired of looking at the old one.

Answer (score 3):

Your point is taken! I completely agree with your assessment. I think this is a change that should be made (and can certainly be, very easily). Keep an eye out for it.